# string to date conversion issue SQL

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, date

I am having an issue with the conversion below:
I am using two main tables client and cli-identifier(this holds the information column)

I have a column in cli-identifier table called information currently holding dates in two ways (only thing changing is the date value):

```
First: 22/11/16 * Company info A/C
Second: 22/11/2016 * Company info A/C
```

I use the following query to slice the information out of the column:

```
 left(Substring(ci.information, charindex('[0-9]',ci.information),103)
     ,charindex('*',ci.information + '*')-2) as datereceived
```

After which I am receving the follow strings:
[example of the two different types showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgOPk.png)

```
22/11/16
22/11/2016
```

I require these converted date/time or just date but unable to do so with the following code (I have also tried using cast to do this too):

```
convert(date,left(Substring(ci.information, charindex('[0-9]',ci.information),103),
 charindex('*',ci.information + '*')-2),1) as datereceived
```

Other methods I have tried is to convert this into a temp table and then using the following to cast the date.

```
select 
 cast (t AS date()
 from #a
```

I know the confliction lies in the date value being formatted as 22/11/**16** any input would be helpful.  Only solution I think of is adding to a temp table and making a query to insert the '20' value infront of the  22/11/**16** year.

Comment: Is it sql or mysql?

Comment: sorry it is just sql had the wrong tag added.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `SQL Server`, you can do this, just detect for length of the date string and use style 3 or 103

```
select  CONVERT( DATETIME , '22/11/16', 3),
        CONVERT( DATETIME , '22/11/2016', 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay thank you.
I added the following to count for length of strings.

```
case when len(left(Substring(ci.information, charindex('[0-9]',ci.information),103),charindex('*',ci.information + '*')-2)) >= 10

 then convert(date,left(Substring(ci.information, charindex('[0-9]',ci.information),103),charindex('*',ci.information + '*')-2),103)

 else convert(date,left(Substring(ci.information, charindex('[0-9]',ci.information),103),charindex('*',ci.information + '*')-2),3)
 end as datereceived
```

Regards,